# Безопасность аторизации/регистрации/сессиям в чистом PHP

Tags: php, auth

Это скорее не вопрос как исправить то, что не работает а как защитить то, что работает. Прочитал что хранить `user_id` в `$_SESSION` небезопасно, но тогда и непонятно как его узнать после авторизации.

```
//Авторизация
session_start();

if(!empty($_POST['email']) && $_POST['password'])) {
   $email     = $_POST['email'];
   $password  = $_POST['password'];
}

//Проверяем есть ли такой юзер в базе по логину и паролю и совпадают ли они
$isAccount = $database->has("account", [
        
    "email"    => $email,
    "password" => $password

]);

//Узнаем по email user_id и role
if ($isAccount) {

    $userdata = $database->select("account", [
        "user_id",
        "role",
        "email"
    ], [
        "email" => $email
    ]);

    foreach ($userdata as $user) {

    }

    //Записываем дату и время последнего входа
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $database -> update("account", [
        "last_login" => $date
    ],[
        "user_id" => $user['user_id']
    ]); 
        
    //И вот здесь возникает вопрос, правильно ли это?
    //Может будут какие рекомендации?
    $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] = [
        "user_id"    => $user['user_id'],
        "role"       => $user['role']
    ];

}
```

Далее в header на страницах `user_id` берется так:

```
session_start();

if (!empty($_SESSION['user_logged_in'])) {
    $user_auth = $_SESSION['user_logged_in'];
    $user_id = $user_auth['user_id'];
}else{
    $user_auth = false;
}
```

Comment: Где прочитали?..

Comment: В интернетиках)) А что не так страшно? Тогда не буду парится так сильно по этому поводу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При создании сессии создается уникальный идентификатор, который отправляется браузеру в виде куки и сохраняется на пользовательском компьютере:
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/session.examples.basic.php
Такой способ имеет потенциальные угрозы в зависимости от настроек на стороне пользователя, вот некоторые потенциальные примеры:
https://habr.com/ru/post/120636/
Поэтому для защиты обычно добавляют различные дополнительные способы, например:

- сохраняют в сессии IP пользователя;
- сохраняют данные системы;
- сохраняют данные браузера;
- сессию дополняют идентификаторами сеанса, чтобы исключить повторное обращение пользователя;
  и т.п.

В частности в вашем примере проверка не происходит никакая, только на наличие данных в сессии.

Так же в вашем примере похоже есть ошибка:
при сохранении данных сессии вы создаете массив второго уровня

```
    $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] = [
    "user_id"    => $user['user_id'],
    "role"       => $user['role']
];
```

а при проверке данных обращаетесь вообще к массиву $user_auth

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['user_logged_in'])) {
$user_auth = $_SESSION['user_logged_in'];
$user_id = $user_auth['user_id'];
```

}

Т.е. в вашей сессии достаточно просто получить идентификатор сессии и можно подключаться к серверу

Comment: И снова работа возвращает меня к этому вопросу))  Все равно не пойму в чем опасностью моего кода, я в консоли браузера ничего кроме PHPSESSID не вижу, но это не  id юзера. В куки я ничего не пишу, при Logout сессия убивается а PHPSESSID вроде убивает сессию после закрытия браузера. По ссылке в вашем примере пишут о конкретно защите при хранении пароля например но у меня только user_id и все. Больше мне ничего не требуется. И вот не понятно одни пишут можно хранить другие пишут что нельзя.

Comment: У Вас нет проверки идентификаторов на стороне сервера - в этом проблема. Если вы просто берете куки (сессию), как достаточное основание для доступа в админ функции, то при копировании куки возникает возможность подключиться с другого браузера, системы, компьютера. Т.е. в вашем случае сессия - это ключ, которым может открыть дверь кто угодно, главное, чтобы у него был ключ. Для безопасности, как вариант, можно проверить, что дверь открывает именно тот, кому мы дали ключ.